# How to partial update Marten ORM document

Tags: c#, postgresql, marten

I looking for the most efficient way to update a single property in an existing Marten Document, stored within a Postgres database (V 10). For example, assuming User is defined as:

```
public class User(){

    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}

}
```

and I have a user saved in a users database, with Id: 1, Name: Joe, Age: 30.  Then I want to update the value of Name to Joe Smith, I could:

Query the sever for the document, update the document and save it again:

```
DocumentStore store = // omitted for brevity
User user;

// Get User Document
using (var session = store.OpenSession())
            {
                user = session
                    .Query<User>()
                    .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                    .FirstOrDefault();
            }

// Update user name
user.Name = "Joe Smith";

using (var session = store.LightweightSession())
            {
                session.Store(user);
                session.SaveChanges();
            }
```

But this seems highly inefficient owing to two transactions, one for query and one for save.

I found [Jeremy Miller's discussion](https://github.com/JasperFx/marten/issues/18) from 2015 using Session.Patch and implemented this type of update.  I had to install the [plv8 extension](http://jasperfx.github.io/marten/documentation/admin/installing-plv8-windows/) for Postgres as they seemed to discontinue its inclusion from a few versions prior.  I have the execution in its own method:

```
private void UpdateUserName(string userId, string newName, DocumentStore store)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    Guid userGuid = new Guid(userId);
                    session.Patch<User>(userGuid).Set(u => u.Name, newName );
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This executes without throwing any exception, but doesn't affect change to User document saved in the database.

I'm not sure if there's an error in my Patch,  or if there's simply a better way of doing it using a different Session method that doesn't require the plv8 extension.

**UPDATE:** Resolved Patch not affecting change to the database by adding the SaveChanges() call after the Patch Call as per below:

```
private void UpdateUserName(string userId, string newName, DocumentStore store)
        {
            try
            {

                using (var session = store.OpenSession())
                {
                    Guid userGuid = new Guid(userId);
                    session.Patch<User>(userGuid).Set(u => u.Name, newName );
                    session.SaveChanges(); // <-- force changes to database
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I would still like to know if this is the most efficient way to partially update a document.

Comment: It's worth noting the userGuid for Patch() parameters can be a simple string. Parsing the string to a Guid is not required.